# length of radius of circles between their tangents

Tags: geometry

In this question, we have five circle that touch each other. we draw their tangents. If we know that smallest circle radius is 8 and biggest circle radius is 18, then what is the length of PF?
Note: Lines MB, HN, PF, DR, AE are perpendicular lines CE.
I'm sorry for bad English. Is it possible to help me?
[image: imaage]

Note: 
If we have some parallel lines and two  lines cut them, then we know that:
$\frac{KR}{JS}≠\frac{LQ}{KR}≠\frac{MO}{LQ} ...$
but in this question, we have these ratio? I can't understand. can you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We know by similar triangles that:

$HN/8 = PF/HN = DR/PF = 18/DR = x$ so $18/8 = x^4$.  $x = \sqrt[4]{9/4} = \sqrt{3/2}$ so $PF = 8x^2 = 18/x^2$

So $PF = 8*3/2 = 12$ or $PF = 18/(3/2) = 12$. $PF = 12$.

Comment: can you help me for similar triangle to get $\frac{HN}{8}=\frac{PF}{HN}=\frac{DR}{PF}=\frac{18}{DR}$

Comment: Each triangle from C, to the tangent point of a circle, to the center of the circle are similar.  Each triangle is larger by a factor of x.  the factor of x is determinable by comparing the radii.  Another way to look at it is to see that the quadrilaterals all have equal angles so they are similar.  So the right side of a quadrilateral/left side of a quadrilateral will be proportional.

Comment: thanks. IS it possible to lock at my main question for added information?